# LWJGL cannot find class error when using "java <class file>" command

Tags: java, lwjgl

I successfully compiled my source using this command:

```
javac -classpath "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar" Game.java
```

However, when I try to run it using:

```
java -classpath "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar" Game
```

, it gives me an error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Game
```

What have I done wrong!? :(

I am certain that there are no syntactical errors and class labeling anomalies.

EDIT: I've also tried running the program using this command, but still nothing. T.T

```
java -cp "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar" -Djava.library.path="..\lwjgl-2.7.1\native\windows" Game
```

Comment: it has to be `java -classpath "jarpath" <classname>`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question, but it's revised now. The command I used to run it was `java -classpath "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar" Game`

Comment: Does your `Game` class has a `main()` method?

Comment: Yes, it does. I even tried a blank source with just the imports, the constructor method and the main method, but still nothing.

Comment: Does the `Game` class reside in some package? If so, you've to specify it.

Comment: No, it isn't packaged. It's just there in the folder and does not belong to any package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer, after endless hours of sitting on my toilet...

```
java -cp "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar"; -Djava.library.path="..\lwjgl-2.7.1\native\windows" Game
```

Note the semi-colon after the -cp. The SEMI-COLON. That was all that I was lacking. A FRIGGIN' SEMI-COLON.

I hope nobody commits the mistake I did.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be

```
java -classpath "..\lwjgl-2.7.1\jar\lwjgl.jar" Game
```

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. That's the command I used, I just mistyped the question.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Game.class` inside of that jar file? If not, you probably need to include the path to the class file as well. For the current working directory, try:

```
 java -classpath "../lwjgl-2.7.1/jar/lwjgl.jar:." Game
```

(Maybe that : should be a ; on Windows).